# Why does this mysql query return incorrect rows

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to run the following:

```
SELECT * 
from `picks` 
where `name` = 'test' and `a1` = '1' and `a2` = '2' 
and `a3` = '3' and `a4` = '4' and `a5` = '5' and `a6` = '6' and `a7` = '7' 
and `a8` = '8' and `a9` = '9' and `a10` = '10'
```

But for some reason it returns rows that are incorrect, in the example below column `a3` is `errr` but my query says:

```
and `a3` = '3'
```

**Note: the query data is not numerical but actually text in my main data**

[image: http://i.imgur.com/dA6Wce0.png]

Comment: What is your question?  Please include sample data and results *as text* in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first column name is wrong you have `title` but your looking for `name`
i´m not sure you need the '=' operator, try LIKE instead, when you are trying to match string

Something like:

```
SELECT * from `picks` where `title` LIKE 'title' AND `int_value_container`='1' AND `mixed_values` LIKE 'value123'
```